# Get max timestamp of particular id

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to retrieve the last record of a particular cell id.

My database is

```
driverloc_id   taxi_id  lat    lng    time
-----------------------------------------------
1                1       12     2     2014-03-19 15:20:54 
2                1       14   -12     2014-03-23 21:00:45 
3                2       9      8     2014-03-19 15:23:20 
4                2      100    13     2014-03-23 16:58:33 
5                3       11    12     2014-03-19 16:06:51
6                3        1     2     2014-03-23 18:26:37
```

When I run the following SQL statement to get the latest location of taxi 3

```
    SELECT

taxi_id,
driverloc_lat,
driverloc_long, 
MAX(driverloc_time)

FROM  driverloc 
WHERE taxi_id=3
```

I get record 5 back when I need to get record 6

Comment: Try using unix timestamp

Comment: `driverloc_time` does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `order by` with `limit` if you only want one row for the taxi_id:

```
SELECT taxi_id, driverloc_lat, driverloc_long, driverloc_time
FROM  driverloc 
WHERE taxi_id = 3
ORDER BY driverloc_time desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked :) Would you explain why it needed the order by to work?

Comment: @user3453024 . . . It needs the order by so the most recent time is the first row.  In general, when using `limit` you should always be using `order by`.